# Using JSON.net control serialization of final output

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

using the code...

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    var entity = new Foo();
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
}
```

against the following trivial class structure...

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { FooDate = new DateTimeWrapper(); }
    public DateTimeWrapper FooDate { get; set; }
}

public class DateTimeWrapper
{
    public DateTimeWrapper() { DateTime = DateTime.Now; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

...sets the json variable to...

```
{"FooDate":{"DateTime":"2013-08-30T13:36:15.4862093-05:00"}}
```

The JSON I want to return is...

```
{"FooDate":"2013-08-30T13:36:15.4862093-05:00"}
```

without the embedded DateTime part.  How can JSON.net be used to serialize to this custom JSON and subsequently deserialize the above string to the original object?

EDIT

I am aware the object structure can be simplified to produce the desired output.  However, I want to produce the output with the given object structure.  This code is boiled down to highlight the problem.  I didn't put all the code nor a lengthy explanation of it b/c it isn't pertinent to the question.

Comment: Write a custom `JsonConverter`. SO has many examples about how to use it.

Comment: @I4V his class definitions just don't match the definition of the json he's trying to produce. No need for a custom serializer. There is needless indirection that can be removed instead.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal *needless indirection?* Yes, you are right. Can *JsonConverter* can be used for expected output? Yes.

Comment: @I4V I'm not sure you're agreeing with more or not... He's wrapping a `DateTime` object in his `DateTimeWrapper` class then saying "Why is this nested inside of an object in the json?". What I'm saying is the json he's expecting does not match the definition of his objects and he can simply change the definition of his objects to produce the expected json. That indirection serves no purpose.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I think, John explained it in your answers' comments.

Comment: @I4V yeah, I hadn't read that yet. I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in comments, It can easily be done by creating a custom *JsonConverter*

```
var entity = new Foo();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, new DateTimeWrapperConverter());
```

---

```
public class DateTimeWrapperConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTimeWrapper);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //Left as an exercise to the reader :)
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = value as DateTimeWrapper;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj.DateTime);
    }
}
```